# SNMP Manager for LWIP Stack/LLDP for LWIP

Tags: cortex-m, lwip

I run the LWIP-Stack on a Cortex M3 controller. Is there already an SNMP Manager for LWIP-Stack available? I only need to send SNMP "Get" requests to get the MAC-Address from the Link-Partners MIB.

Or does the LWIP-Stack directly support LLDP, so that I can get the MAC-Information of the Link-Partner from my LWIP-Stack?

Thanks a lot.
Stefan